# An Issue with Numerical Evaluation of Coverage Probability

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically evaluate the following coverage probability expression:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
NN = 50;
ra = 4 10^3;
h = 120;
alpha = 25/10;
m = 2;
x0 = 500;
betadB = 0;
beta = 10^(betadB/10);
wp = Sqrt[(ra + x0)^2 + h^2];
wm = Sqrt[(ra - x0)^2 + h^2];
d = Sqrt[ra^2 + h^2];

\[Theta][w_] := ArcCos[(w^2 + x0^2 - d^2)/(2 x0 Sqrt[w^2 - h^2])]
\[Phi][w_] := ArcCos[(x0^2 + d^2 - w^2)/(2 x0 ra)]

Fw1[w_] := (w^2 - h^2)/ra^2
fw1[w_] := (2 w)/ra^2

Fw2[w_] := ((w^2 - h^2)/(\[Pi] ra^2)) (\[Theta][w] - 1/2 Sin[2 \[Theta][w]]) + 1/\[Pi] (\[Phi][w] - 1/2 Sin[2 \[Phi][w]])
fw2[w_] := ((2 w)/(\[Pi] ra^2)) ArcCos[(w^2 + x0^2 - d^2)/(2 x0 Sqrt[w^2 - h^2])]

AA[ss_, rr_] := (NIntegrate[(1 + (ss ua^-alpha)/m)^-m (fw1[ua]/(1 - Fw1[rr])), {ua, rr, wm}] + NIntegrate[(1 + (ss ua^-alpha)/m)^-m (fw2[ua]/(1 - Fw1[rr])), {ua,wm, wp}])^(NN - 1)
BB[ss_, rr_] := (NIntegrate[(1 + (ss ua^-alpha)/m)^-m (fw2[ua]/(1 - Fw2[rr])), {ua, rr, wm}])^(NN - 1)

Pca = NIntegrate[(Sum[((-1)^k/Factorial[k])*D[AA[ss, rr], {ss, k}], {k,0, m - 1}] /. ss -> m beta rr^alpha) NN (1 - Fw1[rr])^(NN - 1) fw1[rr], {rr, h, wm}]; 
Pcb = NIntegrate[(Sum[((-1)^k/Factorial[k])*D[BB[ss, rr], {ss, k}], {k, 0, m - 1}] /. ss -> m beta rr^alpha) NN (1 - Fw2[rr])^(NN - 1) fw2[rr], {rr, wm, wp}];

Pc = Pca+Pcb
```

The code should outputs a numerical value for `Pc` which, in this particular case, should be `0.29`.

#### Update

I have modified the code and tested it with `m=1`. The output in this case should be `0.278` and my code returned `0.27777`, which is indeed correct. However, for `m=2`, the code returns `0.148485` which is not the desired result. It seems that increasing `m` drastically decreases `Pc` which shouldn't be the case. Instead, the output is expected to either increase a bit or saturate. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this? I couldn't pinpoint the source of problem.

Comment: The `Pc =...` line is trying to evaluate symbolically; you need to delay evaluation until the functions get numerical values. The simplest way to do that is to change your function definitions to require numerical input, as in `FB[rr_?NumericQ]:=...`

Comment: @DanielW  Delay all function definitions? My variables (`w`,`ua`,`rr`,`ss`) are all random variables, and hence no numerical values are to be assigned to them. Instead, they are to be integrated along their PDFs. Should I still delay in this case?

Comment: @DanielW I did try to delay all functions yet still getting `General::ivar` error (code is still running). I don't know if I'll be getting a numerical value after all.

Comment: Did you not ask this same question 4 days ago?  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177157/mathematica-takes-too-long-to-evaluate.

Comment: @JimB yeah but I got a comment saying it's to be closed due to too many syntax errors so I fixed them and posted it again. Sorry if that's against policy! I am a newbie here.

Comment: I don't see any comments saying that it would be closed (although maybe those were deleted by whoever posted the comment) or any votes to close it.  But the advice that you haven't seem to have followed is that of @Rom38.  For example, do you really know that the functions `AA` and `BB` really work as desired?

Comment: @JimB Yeah the comment was deleted. I did try to evaluate `AA[1,1]` and got `{4.28939*10^17}` and the errors: `NIntegrate::slwcon` and `NIntegrate::ncvb`. I also evaluated `BB[1,1]` but it did not return a numerical value (I got the error `Integrate::idiv`). The problem with these expressions is that they are complicated and sometimes result in complex values if the numerical values assigned are not properly chosen.

Comment: @Lod Ok, usually when I see code with Integrate inside functions the ?NumericQ fix works. Your problem is deeper; you are trying to take symbolic derivatives of `AA` and `BB` which contain integrals that do not have symbolic closed forms. However, the kernel is going to spend a lot of time trying to find the solution anyway, and, because of the `:=` used to define `AA` and `BB`, it is going to repeat the same very long symbolic integration every single time it `AA` or `BB` is called during the integration of `Pc`.

Comment: @DanielW Yes I have realized that and thus tried using `=`  instead to accelerate the computations. The code is still running and there has to be something wrong.